# WebFlux & formation DTO

Tags: spring-webflux, dto

Hello recently started studying Webflux.

And sometimes I encounter the tasks that you need to form a simple DTO and return it
Take for example the usual class dto

```
  @Data
  @Builder
  public static class Dto {

    private long id;
    private String code1;
    private String code2;
  }
```

And a primitive service with two methods...

```
  @Nullable Mono<String> getCode1(long id);
  @Nullable String getCode2(long id);
```

And wrote a method that forms at the output of Mono

```
  private Mono<Dto> fill(long id) {
var dto = Dto.builder()
    .id(id)
    .build();

//doOnNext
var dtoMono1 = service.getCode1(id)
    .map(code -> {
      dto.setCode1(code);
      return dto;
    })
    .doOnNext(innerDto -> innerDto.setCode2(service.getCode2(id)));

//map
var dtoMono2 = service.getCode1(id)
    .map(code -> {
      dto.setCode1(code);
      return dto;
    })
    .map(unused -> service.getCode2(id))
    .map(code -> {
      dto.setCode1(code);
      return dto;
    });

//just
var dtoMono3 = Mono.just(dto)
    .flatMap(innerDto -> service.getCode1(innerDto.getId()));

//just
var dtoMono4 = Mono.fromCallable(() -> dto)
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic())
    .flatMap(innerDto -> service.getCode1(innerDto.getId()));
}
```

QUESTION:

1. Is it possible to simply create DTO and use it in the Webflux call
   chain ... Or I need to wrap it in **mono.just** or **mono.fromcallable**
   (what are the pros and cons)
2. How best to fill in values via **doOnNext**
   or through **MAP**. An extra line (Return DTO) appears in the case of
   MAP and some people also told me if for example **NULL** comes, **doOnNext** will
   miss it and go further to fill up current dto. But on the other, the **MAP** is used
   to transform the object, and the **doOnNext** is more for debugging and
   logging

Thanks you...

Answer (score 1):

How about using `zip` operator in such a case?
I hope this example can help you:

```
private Mono<Dto> fill(long id) {
    return Mono.zip(someService.getCode1(id), Mono.just(someService.getCode2(id)))
            .map(tuple ->
                    Dto.builder()
                            .id(id)
                            .code1(tuple.getT1())
                            .code2(tuple.getT2())
                            .build()
            );
}
```